# How to import one Excel file sheet to another Excel file in new sheet programmatically

Tags: python, excel, powershell

I have two excel files with multiple sheets in it, I want to import one sheet from the second excel file to first excel file as new sheet programmatically.  While importing I want to retain formatting of the sheet
Looking solution in Python or PowerShell. Didn’t find anything in the search, hence posting this question.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the great PowerShell module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel).

Comment: Is this just a local execution thing or cloud thing?

Comment: @Skin looking to run in local windows machine

Comment: Try looking at [Copy Data from Excel Sheets in Python](https://blog.aspose.com/copy-data-from-excel-sheets-in-python/?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=D97A2E8B7BB54C78A829B186574B326A).

Answer (score 1):

Very basic boilerplate Powershell script ...

```
$excelApplication = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

$sourceWorkbook = $excelApplication.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\Source.xlsx")
$sourceWorksheet = $sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

$destinationWorkbook = $excelApplication.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\Destination.xlsx")

$sourceWorksheet.Copy($destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1))
$destinationWorkbook.Save()

$excelApplication.Quit()
```

It will need work to make it perfect but it's something to run with.

Comment: Don't you feel a little bit like you just did someones homework now? ;-)